# Read browser history

Tags: jquery, security

In http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/tools/spyjax/ there is a script that reads browser history. Its not the javascript history object. It checks the color of links that changes if the link was visited or not.

Is there a script like this but in jquery?

Comment: Why would you want to depend on something that can be manipulated easily by CSS?

Comment: Well, you can add your own CSS to prevent manipulation by other CSS. (Apart from user stylesheets, which I’d be happy to bet virtually no-one uses.)

Comment: @AJ this is not a real life project. I only wanted to see, how easy this is. And it is easy. OMG I have to change my profile to use a non real name now.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't read browser history, but rather relies on a "trick" that a visited link will have a different color (css :visited).

You can do the same thing by hiding all the relavent links* and then showing only the ones that have been visited:

```
$(function() {
  $("#somed a").hide();
  $("#somed a:visited").show();
});
```

Then in your code:

```
<div id="somed">
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com">facebook</a>
 <a href="http://twitter.com">twitter</a>
 <!-- ... more ... -->
</div>
```

*Or do the 'hiding' in CSS right off the bat:

```
#somed a {
  display:none;
}
```